# Mapping Plot Accessories with Random Choices

Tags: plotting

I am plotting two functions (some times `n` functions) as below:

```
Plot[{ Sin[t]^2, Cos[t]^2}, {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]},

 PlotStyle ->
 {{RGBColor[1.0, 0.378, 0.4], Thickness[0.006], 
  AbsoluteDashing[{15, 5}]}, {RGBColor[0.1, 0.2, 0.9], 
  Thickness[0.005]}}
, Frame -> True,
FrameStyle -> {{{Thickness[0.001], 14, 
 Bold}, {Directive[Thickness[0.001]], 14, 
 Bold}}, {{Thickness[0.001], 16, Bold}, {Thickness[0.003], 16, 
 Bold}}},
FrameLabel -> {Column[{Style["x", 15, Italic]}], None},

Epilog -> {Inset[
Text[Style["(a)", 16, Bold, Lighter[Lighter[Black]]]], {2 \[Pi] - 
  0.75, -0.15}],

 Style[Text[
 "Sin[t\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(]\), \(2\)]\)", {\[Pi], -0.077}], 
14], Style[
Text[" Cos[t\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(]\), \(2\)]\)", {1.5, -0.10}], 
14]

 }, PlotRange -> {{0, 2 \[Pi]}, {-1, +1}}, ImageSize -> 500]
```

In the above we have some applications same as `PlotStyle`& `Frame`&`FrameStyle` and so on......

My first question is: is it possible we package all these applications in a box and apply that to any functions differing from `Sin^2` and `Cos^2`. By this possibility we won't need to write or copy all these accessories to the new set of functions. For example `Tan` or `Cot` or ......

and my second question is: in the above plotting and in the `plotstyle` we should have a degree of freedom to select new colors for new set of functions in order to prevent repeated colors for some sets of functions to be plotted. but in choosing the colors we should have an order. we know we can choose colors from the map:

```
map = {"Default" -> 97, "Earth" -> 98, "Garnet" -> 99, "Opal" -> 100, 
"Sapphire" -> 101, "Steel" -> 102, "Sunrise" -> 103, 
"Textbook" -> 104, "Water" -> 105, "BoldColor" -> 106, 
"CoolColor" -> 107, "DarkColor" -> 108, "MarketingColor" -> 109, 
"NeonColor" -> 109, "PastelColor" -> 110, "RoyalColor" -> 111, 
"VibrantColor" -> 112, "WarmColor" -> 113};
```

In each number there are 15 colors can be characterize with RGB codes as below:

`Defer[RGBColor] @@@ ColorData[104, "ColorList"] // Column`
(I can't copy the code of below result because it will be confusing I just copy the image of that)
   [image]

In the `Plotstyle` application we should 
1- Randomly pick up one of the color set in `map` for example `"Textbook" with number`104` 
2- after choosing the color set, we shall randomly choose some colors with RGB codes as brought out in the above picture (For example the second one of 104: RGBColor[0.75, 0.315, 0.], seventh one of 104: RGBColor[0.629898, 0.28, 0.684772] and .....) and the number of selected color data (for example 2 or 3 or 10 but <=15) must be equal to the number of plots.